# Rewrite rule to remove all non alphanumeric symbols from a URI

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I could not find the exactly the same question on SO. I hope someone can help me out with this.

Say, user entered `http://www.example.com/abc#!def`, and what I want to do is remove all symbols in the `${REQUEST_URI}` portion, then do a redirect to `http://www.example.com/abcdef`. The problem is that these symbols can occur anywhere in the string, e.g. `#ab!cdeg` and `abcdef#!` should both redirect to `abcdef`.

If I'm correct, there is no string replace function for mod_rewrite, so this seems impossible to do, but am I correct?

Comment: I believe you're correct - you'll need to pass that URI to your script for further processing, and then the result to a 301 redirect.

Comment: @MikeAnthony, Wait, I think it is possible. I can probably use the N flag. No? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n

Comment: I haven't tested that, but I think it could work. It seems to be quite logical... Let's see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture specific parts of an URL with [regular expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) in a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)
or [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), but not remove arbitrary characters.

Furthermore, you will never see the [hash character '#'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and everything after it in a URL, because it is used by the client to navigate to a specific part of the document.

**Update** using the [next](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n) flag:

```
RewriteRule (.*)[^a-zA-Z](.*) $1$2 [N]
```

This rule removes all characters, which are not `^` alphabetic.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I think I can use the N flag (See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n)). I will fiddle with it and let you know. Meanwhile, if someone already knows that it works, please let us know. It's probably faster to do it in PHP though. I heard .htaccess is slow and using it should be avoid if possible.

Comment: @CookieMonster This is a great idea, I didn't think of that. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I tried your example, and also the same one shown on the Apache documentation, i.e. ewriteRule (.*)A(.*) $1B$2 [N], but both of them are not working. Could it be due to my server setting...? I use XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1 which runs Apache 2.4.3.

Comment: @CookieMonster What exactly means "not working"? The RewriteRule works fine in my test environment. But you won't catch `#` or `?` with that of course.

Comment: Oops, I made a really silly mistake... It's working after I fixed that! Thank you very much!!